# Google Sheets Using Results from one query to return results in another (Nest or Join)

Tags: arrays, date, sorting, google-sheets, google-query-language

I've created a spreadsheet to track my trades using data exported from my brokerage. my spreadsheet has the following simplified format:

| Date | Time | Symbol | Quantity | Amount | Starting Balance | Ending Balance | Trade No. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/1/2022 | 07:00 | ABCD | +1 | -$50 | $100 | $50 | 1 |
| 07/15/2022 | 11:00 | EFGH | +1 | -$25 | $50 | $25 | 2 |
| 07/15/2022 | 13:00 | EFGH | -1 | $50 | $25 | $75 | 2 |
| 07/15/2022 | 11:00 | ABCD | -1 | $75 | $75 | $150 | 1 |
| 08/1/2022 | 06:00 | EFGH | +1 | -$25 | $150 | $125 | 3 |
| 08/1/2022 | 11:00 | EFGH | -1 | +$50 | $125 | $175 | 3 |

What I'm trying to do is get the starting and ending balance for each month/year. This might not be the correct way to do it but I've resorted to using the QUERY method since my pivot table didn't work. I have an initial query that gets the MIN and MAX ROW for each month/year combination:

```
=QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(ARRAYFORMULA(YEAR(Daily_Trades!A5:A))&"-", ARRAYFORMULA(MONTH(Daily_Trades!A5:A)))), ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(Daily_Trades!A5:A)), Daily_Trades!Q5:Q}, "SELECT Col1, MIN(Col2), MAX(Col2) WHERE Col1 <> '1899-12' GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'Year-Month', MIN(Col2) 'Min Row Index', MAX(Col2) 'Max Row Index'" )
```

Now I'm trying to take the results from the query above which look like this:

| Year-Month | Min Row Index | Max Row Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-7 | 1 | 4 |
| 2022-8 | 4 | 5 |

My desired output is the table below with the Starting and Ending Balances for the month/year based on the row indexes. However, since I can't use INDEX in an ARRAYFORMULA and I can't use VLOOKUP because that's based on a cell value I'm not sure how to do this. I was hoping for nested or joined queries but not sure if that's possible either.

| Year-Month | Starting Balance | Ending Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-7 | 100 | 150 |
| 2022-8 | 150 | 175 |

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: @player0 the last table in the question....Sorry I'll update that so it's more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({SORTN({TEXT(A2:A, "e-m"), F2:F}, 9^9, 2, 1, 1), 
 INDEX(SORTN(SORT({TEXT(A2:A, "e-m"), G2:G}, 1, 1, 2, 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 1),,2)}, 
 "where Col3 is not null", )
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=QUERY({"Year-Month", "Starting Balance", "Ending Balance"; 
 SORTN({TEXT(A2:A, "e-m"), F2:F}, 9^9, 2, 1, 1), 
 INDEX(SORTN(SORT({TEXT(A2:A, "e-m"), F2:F}, ROW(F2:F), 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 1),,2)}, 
 "where Col3 is not null", 1)
```

Comment: Almost there. :) I have more data in my spreadsheet and for some reason the 2022-7 data just stops at a certain point which just happens to be 7/15/2022 date...so my ending balance isn't the true last one for the month. I'm trying to figure what's the culprit

Comment: @user1015196 if you see: 7/15/2022 it means that you don't have a valid date. 7th day of 15th month

Comment: My dates are in mm/dd/yyyy format and 7/15/2022 is a valid date and it's actually showing up to that date. I changed your formula to use TEXT(A2:A, "yyyy-mm").

Comment: @user1015196 can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Sure

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YBuD4aZ24Dek0z-z-NsLdm4gd7-Ul2AVaPss9rVZPrE/edit?usp=sharing